# HTML5 video changes width/height or glitches when loading new video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to get it so the HTML5 video player smoothly loads and transitions to another video or plays back the video. However, when it does reload the file, the video disappears and then reappears. I don't want that to happen. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head></head>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <video id="myVideo" width="320px" height="240px" autoplay controls onended="replay()">
     <source src="capture.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
 <script>
     var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
     function replay()
     {
        vid.src = "capture.webm";
        vid.load();
        vid.play();
     }
 </script>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

How would I make the player look smooth and simply replay without the player disappearing and then reappearing when it reloads and plays the video?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem on the latest Google Chrome (albeit, using a `mp4` video rather than a `webm`): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db826g0v/).

Comment: In that example, the video itself change its height and width when it loaded the new video. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: One thing I want to clarify is what happens is now the player controller doesn't move, but the video itself turns lack, resizes, and then goes back to its original size. Is there a way to smoothly transition to the next video(load) without this happening?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see in your markup is the units in width and height attributes. Try without px unit. The video player assumes it as pixels by default. You would see flickering or change in size if the width and height are not set or incorrect.

```
 <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay controls onended="replay()">
      <source src="capture.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

Comment: It should actually understand it as pixels whether the `px` suffix is used or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `video.videoHeight` to get video's size after video was loaded, but i found some resources can not get videoHeight event i get them after loading.

here is example:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
  console.log(video.videoHeight); // some resources can not get this value
});
video.src = RESOURCE_ADDRESS;
video.load();
```